# Handle Font in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

Here is my context :
We are using WPF to create an new Windows user interface for our product. As we are cross-platform, all information as `Label.Content` or `Button.Content` are known in an other part of the application (written in C), and not defined in XAML.

Here is the problem :
We want to handle Strings that we put in a WPF component's content.
I see that we have some attributes as 
`Label.Content.FontFamily` or `Label.Content.Size`, but graphic attributes are not necessary the same for all the String.

For exemple :
This is my label's content : "Hello guys, thank you to help me". Is it possible to

- Underline "thank you"
- Change all uppercases in Red color
- Change the size of these uppercases

Actually, we are using WinFroms to do that, but it is time to renovate the GUI, because Winforms are just ugly now.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If there are some conditions which changes display styles, you can use [triggers](http://wpftutorial.net/Triggers.html).  Check [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197474/textblock-style-triggers) which describes using.

Comment: Try this in xaml ..............  <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="H" Foreground="Red" FontSize="30"></Run>
        <Run Text="ello," FontSize="13"></Run>
        <TextBlock Text="Thank you" TextDecorations="Underline" ></TextBlock>
        <Run Text="to help me" Foreground="Blue"/>
    </TextBlock>................

Comment: Unfortunatlly, in my case changing XAML il probably not a good solution. When I don't know how to "design" the string before recieve it. I know, it is not realy in the WPF philosophy, but i seems impossible with our API structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TextBlock's Content property (Text) expects a collection of `Inline` elements (InlineUICollection), you have the following available:

```
       Inline
          InlineUICollection
          LineBreak
          Run (defines Text property)
          Span (defines Inlines property)
            Bold
            Italic
            Underline
```

(Inlines is the Content property for span and it's an InlineUICollection, meaning that you can add Run and LineBreaks and other Spans/Bold/Italic inside Span.)

Using this it is possible to "Hello guys, thank you for helping me":

```
<TextBlock><Run Text="H" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red"/><Span>ello guys, <Underline>thank you</Underline> for helping me</Span></TextBlock>
```

The H will be red and bigger, and thank you will be underlined.

This is all possible programmatically as well, for example, "hello world" using a run in a textblock:

```
        TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
        t.Inlines.Add(new Run{Text="Hello World"});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. It seems to be that I'm looking for. But I suppose it is not possible to do the same for a Button, or a ListBox ?

Comment: Yes you can. A Button is a ContentControl so you can customize how it looks through a ContentTemplate. If you are ok with the default look and feel you can just add a TextBlock as the content of the button and it will be displayed, i.e.: `<Button><TextBlock><Run Text="H" FontSize="20" Foreground="Red"/><Span>ello guys, <Underline>thank you</Underline> for helping me</Span></TextBlock></Button>`. For ItemControls (e.g. ListBox) you have to look at how DataTemplates are used, they allow you to define how each item gets rendered