# Multiple Run elements in WPF Style setter

Tags: wpf, styles, textblock

Is it possible in `XAML` to define multiple `Run`'s inside a `Style` setter?

The following has two `Run`'s defined and fails:

> The property 'Value' is set more than once.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
              <Setter Property="Text">
                   <Setter.Value>
                       <Run Text="{Binding SelectedItem.iso}"/>
                       <Run Text="{Binding SelectedItem.value}"/>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
             <Style.Triggers>
                 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.type}" Value={x:Null}">
                      <Setter Property="Text" Value="No value" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Can this be fixed while preserving the usage of multiple `Run`'s?

Comment: This would not work even if a Style Setter would accept multiple values. Multiple Runs are not set to the `Text` property of a TextBlock, but instead to its `Inlines` property. However, `Inlines` is not a dependency property and can therefore not be set by a Style Setter.

Comment: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197474/textblock-style-triggers

It has the two options available for you.

Answer (score 15):

A Setter works on one property, so it can have only one value, the error you get is logical: it has no way of understanding what you're trying to do, it can just... set a property to a given value.

So the idea is to give it this value as it should be: appended texts. To do so, you would use [MultiBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which takes multiple values and returns them as one, depending on the [StringFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you give it:

```
<Setter.Value>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}{2}"><!-- Format as you wish -->
        <Binding Path="SelectedItem.iso"/>
        <Binding Source="{x:Static System:Environment.NewLine}"/>
        <Binding Path="SelectedItem.value"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Setter.Value>
```

*Note on StringFormat: You have to use `{}` at start to escape braces, else it would consider them as markup extension starters.*