# [WPF]How to set multiline text in setter of style

Tags: c, wpf

I need create many TextBlock with same text.

I can set multiline text in TextBlock like this：

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Foreground="Red">the first line</Run><LineBreak />
    the second line
</TextBlock>
```

I want to create a style for those TextBlock, so I try this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="text1">
     <Setter Property="Text">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Run Foreground="Red">the first line</Run>
            <LineBreak />
            the second line
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But it's not work.

I think maybe I should add something in `<Setter.Value>`, I tried a few things but nothing worked, either.

Sorry for bad English and thanks for any idea.

Comment: You could perhaps use a datatemplate.

Answer (score 0):

My friend use other key word find this answer:
[Multiple Run elements in WPF Style setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192277/multiple-run-elements-in-wpf-style-setter/28194174)

It's mean I can't use style set multiple Run elements, so I find other way to solve this problem:

1.Using namespace
`xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

2.Add resource

```
<Window.Resources>
    <sys:String x:Key="myString1">Line1 text</sys:String>
    <sys:String x:Key="myString2">Line2 text</sys:String>
</Window.Resources>
```

3.Use resource

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Foreground="Red" Text="{StaticResource myString1}"/>
    <LineBreak />
    <Run Text="{StaticResource myString2}"/>
</TextBlock>
```